# How do I convert between + and x polarizations of a gravitational wave?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, polarization

Let's say I have a gravitational waveform h(t) that is completely +-polarized. How do I convert it to one that has some x-component? Or is completely x-polarized?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you mean an experimental method, like a sort of 'waveplate'? Or do you mean what mathematical transformation would be needed?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSteane. I want the mathematical transform that can take h(t)=h_+(t) to h_+(t)+h_x(t) for some given phase angle.